# How to check the existance of single Entity? Google App Engine, Python

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

Sorry for noobster question again.

But I'm trying to do some very easy stuff here, and I don't know how. Documentation gives me hints which do not work, or apply.

I recieve a POST request and grab a variable out of it. It says "name".

I have to search all over my entities Object (for example) and find out if there's one that has the same name. Is there's none, I must create a new Entity with this name. Easy it may look, but I keep Failing.
Would really appreciate any help.

My code currently is this one:

```
 objects_qry = Object.query(Object.name == data["name"])

        if (not objects_qry ):
            obj = Object()
            obj .name =  data["name"]
            obj .put()

class Object(ndb.Model):
    name        = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Comment: If you want a unique key and only one entity for a given name, why aren't you using 'name' to create the key for the entity and just use Object.get_by_id()

Comment: But I need to pass through all existing Objects in the database. Or I just don't understand your advice. Could you please give me some code?

Comment: What, exactly, goes wrong when you use this code?

Comment: Its gives me an empty query if thee's no Objects with this name. If I try (not bool(objects_qry)) gives me True.  So I just can't find a way to receive a negative answer when asking if such an Object exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a query to perform this operation is really inefficient.

In addition your code is possibly unreliable, if name doesn't exist and you have two requests at the same time for name you could end up with two records.  And you can't tell because your query only returns the first entity with the name property equal to some value.

Because you expect only one entity for name a query is expensive and inefficient.
So you have two choices you can use get_or_insert or just do a get, and if you have now value create a new entity.

Any way here is a couple of code samples using the name as part of the key.

```
name = data['name']
entity = Object.get_or_insert(name)
```

or

```
entity = Object.get_by_id(name)
if not entity:
    entity = Object(id=name)
    entity.put()
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `.query` just creates a query object, it doesn't execute it, so trying to evaluate is as a boolean is wrong. Query object have methods, `fetch` and `get` that, respectively, return a list of matching entities, or just one entity.

So your code could be re-written:

```
objects_qry = Object.query(Object.name == data["name"])
existing_object = objects_qry.get()

if not existing_object:
  obj = Object()
  obj.name = data["name"]
  obj.put()
```

That said, Tim's point in the comments about using the ID instead of a property makes sense if you really care about names being unique - the code above wouldn't stop two simultaneous requests from creating entities with the same name.

Comment: But what do you excatly mean by "using ID"?

Comment: I my previous little GAE project I made this when I wanted to create a single Entity. editors = Editors(key_name='_editors')   and then I was just retrieving it by key_name. But currently I use ndb.Model, which I guess doesn't have a key_name attribute.

Comment: ndb does have the equivalent to `key_name` its called `id`.  I strongly suggest you take the time to read the docs. There is even a cheat sheet for the lazy https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic

Comment: Tim, you're awesome. Thanks. Great link!